# Scope of variable in a converse statement

Tags: logic

Let $G$ be a group. Consider the statement:
$$
\exists g \in G \to \exists a,b \in G: g=ab\,.
$$

Is the converse of this statement
$$
\exists a,b \in G: g=ab \to \exists g \in G\,?
$$

If so, why can the left/if part reference $g$? In fact is it even allowed to use $g$ in the right/then part of the first statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a *propositional logic* statement of the form 
$ p \to q$
 the converse is $q \to p$,
 so you merely flip the LHS and RHS of the arrow.

With first order logic you have to take more care. Your first statement isn't actually well defined, since the existential quantifier needs to have the whole statement as it's scope to apply to the RHS.

Correcting this depends a bit on what you intend to say; Depends a bit on what you are trying to express. A slight fix would be $$\exists g (g \in G \to \exists a,b(a,b \in G \wedge g = ab))$$
However, I'm guessing you are trying to say that if $g$
 is an element of a group then there exist elements 
$a$ and $b$
 in the group such that $g = ab,$
 which would be $$\forall g (g \in G \to \exists a,b(a,b \in G \wedge g = ab))$$
In this case you really need to define what you mean by "converse"; if you take the converse of the propositional logic statement within the quantifier we get:
$$\forall g (\exists a,b(a,b \in G \wedge g = ab) \to g \in G)$$
which says that for all $g,$ if $g$ is the product of two elements in the group $G$ then $g \in G,$ which is indeed true.